# Rewriting this complex square root

Tags: complex-numbers

for some reason I can to figure out how to rewrite this square root.
I have:

$\sqrt{2+i}$

And I need to rewrite it into:

$\frac{\sqrt{2(\sqrt{5} + 2)} + \sqrt{-2(\sqrt{5} - 2)}}{2}$

Can anybody show me I to do this? I've been trying for an hour now..

Comment: **Hint:** $\sqrt{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta} = \cos(\theta/2) + i \sin(\theta / 2)$.  Note $2 + i = \sqrt{5} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\right)$

Comment: Solve $(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy=2+i$.

Comment: @DaneBouchie Read that again.  I say
$$
2 + i = \sqrt{5} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\right)
$$

Comment: Ah, my bad. I read $.$ as a period for some reason. Even then, lazy reading on my behalf.

Answer (score 2):

One can use trigonometry for sure but I thing the fastest way to solve this is just to solve the quadratic.
$$(x+yi)^2=2+i$$ so

$$x^2-y^2=2$$
$$2xy=1$$

and $$(x^2+y^2)^2=(x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2=4+1=5$$

So $$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{5}$$
(positive since $x$ and $y$ real)
and 
$$x^2=\frac{\sqrt{5}+2}{2}$$
$$y^2=\frac{\sqrt{5}-2}{2}$$

so

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}+2}{2}}$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-2}{2}}$$

Both $x$ and $y$ have same sign since $2xy=1$.