# Find all the solutions of $z^2-(1+3i)z-8-i=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

I am stuck on a problem and I was hoping someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

> I want to find all the roots of:
>
> $$z^2-(1+3i)z-8-i=0$$

There are two ways I tried to approach this.

1. **Quadratic formula:**

$$\begin{align} z_1,z_2 &=-\frac{p}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left( \frac{p}{2}\right)^2-q} \\ & \implies z_1,z_2=\frac{1+3i}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left( \frac{(-1-3i)}{2}\right)^2-(-8-i)}\\ &=  \frac{1+3i}{2} \pm\sqrt{\frac{24+10i}{4} }=\frac{1+3i \pm\sqrt{24+10i}}{2}\end{align}$$

2. **Completing the square:**

$$\begin{aligned} z^2-(1+3i)z-8-i &=0 \\ & \iff \left(z-\left( \frac{1+3i}{2}\right) \right)^2-8-i=\left( \frac{1+3i}{2}\right)^2 \\ & \iff u^2=\frac{24+10i}{4} \\ & \iff u=\pm\frac{\sqrt{24+10i}}{2} \\ & \iff z_{1,2}=\frac{1+3i \pm\sqrt{24+10i}}{2}\end{aligned}  $$

Using both methods I arrive at the same result. However, wolframalpha tells me the roots are:

$$z_1=-2+i \\ z_2=3+2i$$

I have tried everything (writing it in in exponential form, graphing, etc.) but I have no idea how I can arrive at those two roots. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find square roots $\;\pm(a+ ib)\;$ of $\;24+10i,\;$ solve the equation
$$(a+ib)^2=24+10i.$$
Real and imaginary parts of RHS and LHS are equal, and also absolute values:

$$\begin{aligned}a^2-b^2&=24\\ 2ab&=10\\a^2+b^2&=26\end{aligned}$$
We get $a^2=25$ and $ab=5$ hence $b$ has the sign of $a.$ This gives the two square roots $\pm(5+i).$

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I am new to complex roots and complex polynomials so I didn't immediately think of doing this. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

That's just because the square roots of $24+10i$ are $\pm(5+i)$.

Comment: I should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact: $$ 24+10i = (5+i)^2$$

Comment: I should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Expanding $$(5+i)^2=25+10i-1$$

Comment: I should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849747/rewriting-this-complex-square-root?r=SearchResults) for how to extract complex square roots.  Note carefully:  when you have an odd prime root of a complex number you can't extract it except with trigonometry, but square roots can be rendered by algebra alone.

Comment: Ah I see. I would have do use de moivres formula then right?

Comment: For odd prime roots yes.  For square roots no.

Comment: So for example: $z^8=-3+\sqrt{3}i$ I could solve without de moivres formula?

Comment: Yup, you just do three square root extractions.  The algebra gets complicated but the concept works.